# Div que Pode ser Arrastada

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Gostaria de permitir usuários moverem algumas coisas do meu site.
Do tipo, o usuário poderia arrastar o menu para outro lugar para posicionar melhor a leitura.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Existe várias maneiras de se fazer isto, como:

- Javascript + CSS
- Javascript puro (sem CSS, cria uma "fantasma" do element)
- E com frameworks como jQuery UI ou interact.js

### Com javascript + CSS

Veja que usei `z-index` pra que o objeto fique a frente dos demais quando tiver multiplos elementos

```js
window.onload = function () {
    Dragable(document.getElementById("foo"));
    Dragable(document.getElementById("baz"));
    Dragable(document.getElementById("bar"));
};

//Adiciona eventos pra navegadores modernos e antigos
function addEvent(el, type, callback)
{
    if (el.addEventListener) {
       el.addEventListener(type, callback);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
       el.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    }
}

function Dragable(el)
{
    var isMove = false, //Verifica se esta se movendo
        x = 0, y = 0, //Pega as coordenadas do mouse
        xel = 0, yel = 0; // ultima posição do elemento

    addEvent(el, "mousedown", function (e) {
        isMove = true;

        el.className += " isMoving";

        x = window.event ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
        y = window.event ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;

        xel = x - el.offsetLeft;
        yel = y - el.offsetTop;
    });

    addEvent(document, "mousemove", function (e) {
        if (isMove) {
            e.preventDefault();

            x = window.event ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
            y = window.event ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;

            el.style.left = (x - xel) + 'px';
            el.style.top  = (y - yel) + 'px';
        }
    });

    addEvent(document, "mouseup", function () {
        el.className = String(el.className).replace(/(^|\s)isMoving(\s|$)/g, " ");
        isMove = false;
    });
};
```

```css
#foo, #baz, #bar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fc0;
}

.isMoving {
   z-index: 1001 !important;
}

#baz {
    top: 210px;
    left: 210px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

#bar {
    top: 410px;
    left: 410px;
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="baz"></div>
```

### Com eventos nativos (javascript puro) e o `event.dataTransfer`:

No HTML temos os atributos `ondragstart`, `ondrop` e `ondragover` que servem para este proposito, porém o navegador cria uma imagem fantasma do elemento conforme arrasta, o elemento continua no lugar e só muda de lugar depois do "drop", note que este não posiciona por X e Y, mas sim dentro de outros elementos HTML.

```js
function allowDrop(e) {
    e = e||window.event;

    e.preventDefault();
}

function drag(e) {
    e = e||window.event;

    e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
}

function drop(e) {
    e = e||window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

var area1 = document.getElementById("drop-area-1");
var area2 = document.getElementById("drop-area-2");
var draggable = document.getElementById("draggable-item");

draggable.ondragstart = drag;
area1.ondrop = drop;
area1.ondragover = allowDrop;

area2.ondrop = drop;
area2.ondragover = allowDrop;
```

```css
#draggable-item
{
    background-color: #fc0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#drop-area-1, #drop-area-2
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable-item" draggable="true"></div>

<div id="drop-area-1"></div>
<div id="drop-area-2"></div>
```

### Usando jQuery UI

O jQuery possui uma biblioteca adicional que pode ser baixada neste link [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com)

```js
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

```css
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Clique e arraste</p>
</div>
```

### Usando interact.js

O [interact.js](http://interactjs.io) é uma biblioteca javascript que suporta redimencionar, mover, mobiles, etc.

```js
// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },

    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    // call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                     event.dy * event.dy)|0) + 'px');
    }
  });

  function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  // this is used later in the resizing demo
  window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
```

```css
#drag-1, #drag-2 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 6.5em;
  margin: 10%;

  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;

  border-radius: 0.75em;
  padding: 4%;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

#drag-me::before {
  content: "#" attr(id);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.4/interact.min.js"></script>

<div id="drag-1" class="draggable">
  <p> You can drag one element </p>
</div>
<div id="drag-2" class="draggable">
    <p> with each pointer </p>
</div>
```

### Como inserir JavaScript no HTML

Você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>titulo</title>
    Coloque o arquivos .js e .css aqui
</head>
<body>
    Coloque o conteudo HTML aqui
</body>
</html>
```

Um exemplo deve ser algo como o jquery e jqueryui (no caso estou usando o CDN):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titulo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Clique e arraste</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```