# Como fazer Drag and Drop de button em um textarea?

Tags: html5, drag-n-drop

Estou criando um editor de emails e nele terá alguns macros, fiz alguns exemplos de drag and drop utilizando imagens, gostaria de saber se é possível, ou até mesmo se é interessante utilizar botoes para serem arrastáveis.

Objetivo: Arrastar os botões para o textarea e quando liberar o botão sobre ele inserir apenas o texto contido no botão.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<button>[CODIGO_CLIENTE]</button>
<button>[NOME_CLIENTE]</button>

<br>
<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
  
</textarea>
```

Tem esse exemplo, porém ele utiliza o plugin draggable jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/9zn03xzu/1/

Comment: Acho que arrastar elementos dentro de textarea é meio dificil (ou impossivel) a não ser que queria converter em texto, todavia veja isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64329/3635 talvez você possar simular o textarea com contentEdtiable=true.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como você falou, eu gostaria de Arrastar um elemento porém o que vai para o textarea será apenas o texto, então deverá ser feito uma conversão na hora do drop

Comment: Acho que poderia editar a pergunta para se fazer entender melhor, exatamente que texto deseja que seja adicionado? Algum atributo `data-` ou o nome do botão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão com drag & drop nativo (HTML5).

A ideia é associar a string que quiseres no `dragstart` e depois extrair no `drop` para concatenar com o `value` já existente na `textarea`.

```js
function prepareDrag(el) {
  el.addEventListener('dragstart', e => e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', el.textContent))
}
[...document.querySelectorAll('button')].forEach(prepareDrag);

var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('dragover', e => e.preventDefault());
textarea.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  console.log(data);
  textarea.value += data;
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button draggable="true">[CODIGO_CLIENTE]</button>
<button draggable="true">[NOME_CLIENTE]</button>

<br>
<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
  
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se e assim que você queria. E so arrastar o texto para o `textarea`
Obs: Não utilizei um `button` nesse exemplo mas e so adicionar

- [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kWAtJ/205/)

Obs: Nesse exemplo eu utilizei o JQuery UI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js

Aqui vai um outro exemplo que achei no google: [**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/gGAhp/8/)